# Handling infinite values passed to function in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a function that computes a large expression based on Sympy symbols passed as arguments. A very simplified version for readability is:

```
def expr(a):
    return (1+a)/a
```

This generally works but if the passed argument is the infinity symbol then this becomes a NaN, whereas I'd prefer the result to be somehow evaluated as a limit and return 1 (in this simplified case).

Since in my actual code there are many arguments which could be infinite and the expression is quite large, I'd rather avoid an if-else sequence covering every possible combination of infinite-valued arguments.

I've tried using unevaluated expressions but that doesn't seem to work either. Is there a good workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe you can split the expression with `as_numer_denom` or are there many denominators?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the expression as a limit:

```py
from sympy import oo, limit
from sympy.abc import a, x

def expr(a):
    return limit((1 + x) / x, x, a)

print(expr(oo))  # 1
```